# Upload File From View to Controller in .net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, file-upload

I'm trying to create a .net core project with file upload.

In the model I have a class name "Movie" with 2 properties: Image - of type byte[] and Picture - of type IFormFile.

In the view I added a form with the input:

`<input asp-for="Picture" type="file" id="image_upload" />`

And in my controller I have a function like that:

`public IActionResult NewMovie(Movie movie){...`

In the movie object that is passed the property Image and Picture are always NULL.

I tried changing the asp-for from Image to Picture, to change the function to be of type Task, to add IFormFile to the function calling and nothing helped.

I never been able to get the file's data. I need it to be of type byte[] but I'll take anything to help me.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to store the image in a byte array your model only needs an `IFormFile` like this:

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required")]
[Display(Name = "Image")]
[DataType(DataType.Upload)]
public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
if (model.Image == null)
   return View(model);

    string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath,"Your upload path");
    string ImagePath = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + model.Image.FileName;
    string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, ImagePath);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await model.Image.CopyToAsync(fs);
    }
```

Add this to your `form` tag: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.
Its essential for the `type="file"` input to be submitted.

View:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" Other attributes...>
  <div class="custom-file">
   <input asp-for="Model.Image" type="file" class="custom-file-input fileUpload" />
   <label class="custom-file-label fileLabel">Choose file</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And finally you save the `ImagePath` **only** in your db entity.